# Certain distribution related with a spinning motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose that a narrow beam  flash-light is spun around its center which
is located a unit distance from the $x$-axis, in such a way that the angle
between the beam and the line through the center, parallel to $x$-axis varies
uniformly on $[0,1]$ . Consider the random point $X$ at which the beam intersects the $x$-axis when the flash-light has stopped spinning.

Then how to find the distribution of $X$ ?

Comment: The identity: $$X = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{1 - \cos (\theta)}$$ could be useful to you (hoping in the right calculations). Then you apply the change of variables formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will set flashlight to be at $(0,1)$ relative to the origin for simplicity. You can just translate it later. The angle it makes with the horizontal is $\Theta$.

We can find using trigonometry that 
$$\tan \Theta = \frac{1}{X}$$
So
$$X = \frac{1}{\tan \Theta}$$
Hence,
$$P\left(X \leq x\right)=P\left(\frac{1}{\tan \Theta} \leq x \right)$$
Since both $X$ and $\tan \Theta$ are positive and $\tan \Theta$ is increasing for $0 \leq \Theta \leq 1$,
$$P\left(X \leq x\right)=P\left(\Theta \geq \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x} \right)$$
Using the CDF for unifrom distribution, we have
$$P\left(X \leq x\right)=1-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$$
Hence,
$$f_X(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{x^2+1}, & \text{for } x \ge\cot 1 \text {,} \\
   0, & \text{otherwise.} \\
  \end{cases}$$

---

Update: The extended case where $0 \leq \Theta \leq \pi$

For $0 \leq \Theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, both $X$ and $\tan \Theta$ are positive and $\tan \Theta$ is increasing. Thus,
$$P\left(X \leq x\right)=P\left(\Theta \geq \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x} \right)$$

For $0 \leq \Theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, both $X$ and $\tan \Theta$ are negative and $\tan \Theta$ is increasing. Thus,
$$P\left(X \leq x\right)=P\left(\Theta \geq \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x} \right)$$
which is exactly the same as the other subrange.

Using the CDF for unifrom distribution, we have
$$P\left(X \leq x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(1-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Hence,
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi (x^2+1)}$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is $\Theta$ here ?

Comment: Oh so sorry I forgot to define. It is the angle in your question.

Comment: Are you setting the co-ordinates of $X$ to be fixed ? Then how can it vary with $\Theta$ ?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry I meant set the flashlight at that coordinates.

Comment: How would the answer change if the angle between the beam and the line through the center, parallel to $x$-axis were to vary uniformly on $[0,\pi]$ ?

Comment: It should still looks very similar but we likely have to adjust some coefficients in the pdf and be more careful with the signs. I'll get back to you as soon as possible.